# Separating Parallel Output From a Boost Build Compile

Tags: boost-build, bjam

Is it possible to deinterleave the standard output from the execution of a parallel boost build session?  I am interested in knowing which thread compiles which file with the ultimate goal of time tagging each compilation command to debug a possible Intel Compiler / Flexlm problem.

I have written some wrapper scripts where I can pipe the output of bjam and then time tag each line, but I not confident of the origin of each line.

Does bjam, or I guess icpc, have options to time-stamp their outputs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Boost Build (b2/bjam) already de-interleaves (serializes) all of the build output. The output from build actions (i.e. commands) is buffered and only printed when the actions complete. There are also some options that control that buffering:

```
-mx     Maximum target output saved (kb), default is to save all output.
-px     x=0, pipes action stdout and stderr merged into action output.
```

There is no option to time-stamp output though.